# How to get top row cell text from non blank row cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to help out the really nice admin lady for the work christmas orders and run into a bit of a road block. I'm trying to find a way to get the top row text if a person has marked their order cell with a 1. eg;

[image]

The end result should have the name, their meal, salad, desert and date of their next shift. to be formatted something like this..
[image]

I'm used to doing a bunch of vlookups but don't think it would work in this scenario. I have a list of about 300 employees so thought a formula might be easier. you'll be saving christmas!

Comment: For older Excel you could list the names and then next to it do an INDEX/SMALL aggregation, something like: `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$O$1,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF($B2:$O2<>"",COLUMN($A:$N),""),COLUMN(A:A))),"")` (you probably need to adjust the ranges to your needs, but keep the `COLUMN($A:$N)` part starting at A and have the same number of columns as your range. This needs entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`. Drag to the right and down to your needs. For Office 365, list the names and next to them use FILTER, something like `=FILTER($B$1:$O$1,B2:O2<>"")` drag down to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming A1 orientation on both pictures and Sheet1 is the first picture and Sheet2 is the second picture:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$I$1,MATCH("1",INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$I,MATCH($B3&" "&$C3,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),0),0))
```

For each section change the `B`s and `I`s on the Sheet1 references to encompass only those columns that pertain to the type of food.

Comment: Thanking you kindly!